# Error when running gulp --production Vagrant Laravel / Homestead

Tags: vagrant, gulp, laravel-5.1

I set up a `laravel/homestead` environment to study the `Laravel 5.1`, while trying to run `gulp --production` command  get the error below:

`Error: Cannot find module 'strip-bom'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/app/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/getContents/bufferFile.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)`

I've looked hard and found nothing to correct the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `strip-bom` installed. You have to install it like this.

```
npm install --save strip-bom
```